# VBA code required for Msg Box when two value equal in two cells

Tags: vba, excel

I have a worksheet with live data of stock value, high, low, stock name in Column A3:A103, B3:B103, C3:C103, E3:E103  respectively and that updates every few seconds.

I would like to have pop up Msg Box as under;

1) when value in column A is equal to value in column B then Msg Box as "Buy - (stock name)". Stock name is listed in column E.

2) When value in column A is equal value in that of column C then Msg Box as as Sale - (stock name)". Stock name is listed in column E.

For example when A6=B6 then Msg Box should be "Buy - (stock name)" where stock name is E6

Kindly help to provide VBA code for this.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)        
    If Range("A" & Target.Row) = Range("B" & Target.Row) Then
        MsgBox "Buy - " & Range("E" & Target.Row)
    ElseIf Range("A" & Target.Row) = Range("C" & Target.Row) Then
        MsgBox "Sell - " & Range("E" & Target.Row)
    End If
End Sub
```

The key is using the `Worksheet_Change` event in the worksheet where you have your data.

Comment: Alex, Thank you very much for the code. I will try and let you know it on tomorrow as Indian Market is now closed. I don't know about Worksheet_Change event. Column A, B and C data is auto updating as I pasted links from other linked workbook provided by my stock broker.

Comment: Alex, when I am entering two equal value in A1 and B1 manually in my sheet it does not work. Can you help me in this?

Comment: Have you used the debugger? E.g. Does the code execute, which values are compared etc?

Comment: It only works when A1=B1 and then I  double click on E1 and then press enter. It is almost like not working. Plz help.

Comment: It may be that the `Worksheet_Change` event does not capture the automatically updated prices. I am not sure how you are streaming the live prices into your spreadsheet? If you add `Debug.Print Target.Address` at the start of the code that should help you check if a price update is actually triggering the `Worksheet_Change` event

Comment: Alex, alternately, I would like to see only rows where below conditions is fulfilled and hide all other rows to filter out stocks.
Condition 1: =AND(A3=B3,A3>=L3,A3<=K3,A3<>0)
Condition 2 =AND(A3=C3,A3>=S3,A3<=R3,A3<>0) 
Above condition is for example of Raw No.3 and which I am using for conditional formatting.
Kindly help to provide VBA codes for this.

Comment: Did the original code work in the end? For your latest comment - it is better to open a new question.